# How to use FxCop CustomDictionary.xml from the project localization?

Tags: reflection, process, assemblies, code-analysis, fxcop

I create an custom FxCop rule, that need the the path to CustomDictionary.xml, but not this in Program Files, but that used in my FxCop project file. I has tryed to use reflection to Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() and diagnostic to Process.GetCurrentProcess() but no result.
Where should i search such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to access that particular file, or would you simply like to take advantage of the cumulative dictionary contents (as do the Microsoft-provided FxCop rules)?  If the latter, you can use the public Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.NamingService class, which takes care of all the messy dictionary file reading details for you.

Comment: I need access to the particular file, becouse i use my own node naming in the xml:<Acronyms>
        <ControlPrefixes>
      <ControlPrefix Type="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label">lbl</ControlPrefix> as you see i'm trying to make specyfic hungarian notation rule.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against trying to use the custom dictionary in this way, particularly since the information you're adding doesn't really have anything to do with valid spelling.  Instead, you should probably consider creating a configurable rule that implements Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.IConfigurableRule.

Comment: Ok, but one question: it is posible that the configuration file for that rule will be in the project location (*.FxCop file)? Becouse i want to share it with other people using SVN. When someone add new prefix the ohter automaticly know that.

Comment: The configuration for the rule should actually go in the .fxcop file (in the Settings element) instead of in a separate file.  See http://www.yafla.com/dennisforbes/FxCop-Cyclomatic-Complexity/FxCop-Cyclomatic-Complexity.html and http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/11/17/configurable-fxcop-rules.aspx for details.